# MongoDB PHP library how to create database

Tags: php, mongodb, database

I use [MongoDB PHP library](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/api/index.html) in the [client object](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/api/class-MongoDB.Client.html) I can see the method for drop a database, how can I create a new database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have problems with the naming.
In mongodb a DB is called an `Index` and a tabe called a `Collection`.

You will find createIndex in the docs:

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/api/namespace-MongoDB.Operation.html

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/

Answer (score 1):

the namespace `database` is automatically create if it does not exist when we create collection

```php
use MongoDB\Driver\Manager;
use MongoDB\Database;

$manager = new Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$database = new Database($manager, 'newDataBase');
var_dump($database->createCollection('CollectionName'));
```

sorry i keep learning

Comment: Yes, the only way to "create a database" is to use an "x_database" and create a collection, and then database is created :) +1